# MVC 5 not setting parameter named "action" to passed value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following method:

```
public void Service(int id, string action)
```

When i hit this as a Url:

```
http://localhost/home/service?id=24&action=updated
```

MVC is setting my parameter "action" as "service" (the name of the method) regardless of what i pass in to the parameter.

Is there anyway to override this "action" parameter from MVC setting it (via routes or any attributes)?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be renaming parameter, say to "actionName". Is this an option?

Comment: I NEED to keep "action" in order to not break compatibility with previous version... is there any other way besides renaming the parameter?

Comment: So did this used to work in MVC 3?

Comment: No, in this case, i am acting as the receiver... we have APIs that return a callback to the requestor with querystring id=X&action=X... i am pretending i am receiveing the callback and was trying to figure out to override MVC taking over "action".

Comment: My work around is to read the query string NameValueCollection and grab action from there

Comment: If you are trying to use the default binders and controller factories you will have issues with this variable name... but you should be able to get the "action" query string out of the controller context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Request.QueryString["ACTION"]
```

if you are filling in an object with a member called action, it's possible that in the debugger it will appear this has not worked, but it has. check it with Console.WriteLine or another method.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to rename the parameter to something else.

"action" is a special case in ASP.NET MVC, so you need to avoid using it for another purpose.

(Note: this does work correctly in WebAPI)