# Is it possible to have a parameter named action in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**PLEASE MARK AS DUPLICATE** -  [Its already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013997/mvc-5-not-setting-parameter-named-action-to-passed-value)

Is it possible to have a parameter named action in MVC4?

Trying to do this results in the parameter returning me the name of the controller action rather than the parameter value.

```
/Somecontroller/Someaction?action=value
```

When I try to access the parameter action, I get "Someaction" as the result rather than "value".

Trying to bind the parameter to a different name doesn't help either.

```
public ActionResult Someaction([Bind(Prefix = "action")] String id)
```

Edit: I have not found 'Action'/'action' in reserved MVC keywords either.

Comment: Try @ prefix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185782/map-asp-net-mvc-action-parameter-name-to-another-name

Comment: That makes no difference what so ever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 5 not setting parameter named "action" to passed value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013997/mvc-5-not-setting-parameter-named-action-to-passed-value)

Comment: `action` name is a special case in ASP.NET MVC. Rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I would assume you could try changing the url of your default route to something other than action

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

to

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{cAction}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", cAction = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

this should then allow you to use action as a parameter in your Action. I'm not certain why you'd want to do this, I would probably build a route url that accepted my action and built it as part of the url similar to this:

`/SomeController/SomeAction/value` where value is your "action" parameter.

**EDIT based on comments:**

I successfully created a route that goes to an aspx url'd route

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "third-party.aspx", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Obviously you can add whatever controller/action you want here and where you want to handle it, then you access that route via `/third-party.aspx?action=value` and it seemed to work for me

Comment: This doesn't work and results in an exception "System.InvalidOperationException: The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty string value.". The reason why I am asking this is because I have a third-party application that redirects to mine with a parameter named action. I'm not sure as to how to handle it elegantly in MVC.

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't sure if it would actually work, as action, by convention, is reserved, but figured it could be worth trying to override it. Let me try something and get back to you on another possible option